# Repeat content twice on a page (Tables + text)

Tags: tables, fontsize

I am new to LaTeX, and now struggle with how to create a document i need.
Here is a picture of what i need:
[image]

Basically i need a table, that will occupy 3/4 of page width, and text to the right of the table, that will occupy the remaining quarter. And i need this table and text to be repeater on the page twice, as it is shown on the picture.
I can not make it this way because when i fill a table with data, it occupies all the page width, i guess because the font is too big, and i am not able to change it to a smaller one. (While i was trying to look for a solution, someone mentioned that you first need to carefully think if you really want to use smaller font size than 10pt. But without reducing it's size, i don't know if it is possible to do this)

Comment: Have you attempted to create this? If so please add your code to this question. Also, please use proper capitalization.

Comment: People say, 'a picture is worth a thousand words'; but in *TeX, a few words of code are worth a million pictures. This is why you'll see people asking all the time for a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: Does this form part of a bigger document? Otherwise you can create a single page with a single table and duplicate the result on a larger page.

Answer (score 1):

The tables were created using [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) (for ease of column widths). The code was duplicate to create the ... duplicate table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,array}

\pagestyle{empty}% No page header/footer
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indentation
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{.75\textwidth}[t]{ | X | X | X | }
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Title} \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline  
\end{tabularx}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.25\textwidth}@{}}
  \\% Skip the title row
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Aenean mollis at quam et varius. Sed mollis lacus eu diam tincidunt varius. 
  Cras dapibus, risus sit amet condimentum posuere, erat tellus laoreet nulla.
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Some bottom text.

% ============================

\vfill

\begin{tabularx}{.75\textwidth}[t]{ | X | X | X | }
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Title} \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline & & \\
  \hline  
\end{tabularx}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{.25\textwidth}@{}}
  \\% Skip the title row
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
  Aenean mollis at quam et varius. Sed mollis lacus eu diam tincidunt varius. 
  Cras dapibus, risus sit amet condimentum posuere, erat tellus laoreet nulla.
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Some bottom text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it without duplicating all the code? I mean, storing that code in a variable and using that variable later?

Comment: @skan Yes, of course.